# How can I create a global stylesheet to share scss variables in a Nx React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, architecture, nrwl-nx

Now, I really hope this isn't too opinion based. But I would just love to here some advice since I have no idea how to start this.

I have a basic [Nx](https://nx.dev/) workspace with a TypeScript React frontend combined with [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) styles.
The project's architecture looks sort of this:

```
root/
├─ apps/
├─ libs/
│  ├─ someLib1/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  │  ├─ lib/
│  │  │  │  ├─ someLib1.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ someLib1.scss
│  ├─ someLib2/
│  ├─ someLib3/
│  ├─ shared/
│  │  ├─ styles/
│  │  │  ├─ global.scss
```

Is there any clever way how I could import `global.scss` into any accessable (=same folder level or below) component in `/libs`? To give an example:
Imagine I have declared `$example: #fff;` in `global.scss`. How would I use it in `someLib1.scss` without importing it by the absolute path (`@import/@use "../../../shared/styles/global.scss"` or `@import/@use "/libs/shared/styles/global.scss"`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I came up with the following solution:

I added a custom `webpack.config.js` file to my workspace and sort of extended the initial config delivered by [Nx](https://nx.dev/) with an alias of the `global.scss` file.

```
const path = require('path');
const nrwlConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js');

module.exports = (config) => {
  nrwlConfig(config);

  return {
    ...config,
    resolve: {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        'global': path.join(
          __dirname,
          'libs/shared/styles/global.scss'
        ),
      },
    },
  };
};
```

After doing that I was able to import `global.scss` in every `.scss` file in libs by the alias like so:

```
@import "global";
```

Comment: can this be done without webpack?