# Export styles across packages in NX workspace

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm using NX Monorepo where I'm trying to export SCSS variables across packages and apps. In my nx workspace I have one appliaction(nextjs) and one lib(React). My lib package is design system. I can easily export files like js,ts etc because of tsconfig and 'paths' options. However I can't export scss stuff like variables.
Here's my code structure:

```
-ROOT
  -Apps
    -app1
  -Libs
    -lib1(design system)
```

All I want to achieve is export scss stuff into app1 so I don't need to duplicate code.

Comment: Look here https://nx.dev/more-concepts/applications-and-libraries

Comment: @DheerajkumarRao I have read that but I don't think this resolves my issue

Comment: It will definitely solve your issue 
(A) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923383/how-can-i-create-a-global-stylesheet-to-share-scss-variables-in-a-nx-react-proje
(B) https://dev.to/vitorstick/sharing-styles-between-apps-inside-nx-workspace-20i5